# Why redefine the Element type in Swift RandomAccessCollection protocol？

Tags: swift

From the source code

```
public protocol RandomAccessCollection<Element> : BidirectionalCollection where Self.Indices : RandomAccessCollection, Self.SubSequence : RandomAccessCollection {

    associatedtype Element
```

We can see that `RandomAccessCollection` define the `Element` to associatedtype. what's the meaning of this redefinement ?

And Array is conform to this `RandomAccessCollection` protocol . from the Array's source code

```
@frozen public struct Array<Element> {
...

}
```

There will be an `Element` too.

Is there any connections between these 3 Element ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RandomAccessCollection` redeclaring `Element` from `BidirectionalCollection` is not necessary. Removing the declaration would not have broken anything or added any new functionality to the code.

```
protocol Foo<T> {
    associatedtype T
}

protocol Bar<T>: Foo {
    associatedtype T
}
```

compiles to exactly the same thing as:

```
protocol Foo<T> {
    associatedtype T
}

protocol Bar<T>: Foo {

}
```

Try this on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/4vnKa8Yc5)!

The only difference I can see is the documentation that is generated. By redefining `Element`, there are separate pages for [`RandomAccessCollection.Element`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/randomaccesscollection/element) and [`BidirectionalCollection.Element`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bidirectionalcollection/element), linked directly from the pages for `RandomAccessCollection` and `BidirectionalCollection`.

Without redeclaring `Element`, it is less obvious that `RandomAccessCollection` has an `Element` associated type, because you would have had to go to the "[Inherits from](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/randomaccesscollection#inherits-from)" section and go to a protocol that does declare `Element` to see that it indeed has `Element` as an associated type.

That said, you could argue that you can immediately infer that `RandomAccessCollection` has an `Element` associated type by seeing `Element` is its primary associated type in its declaration:

```
protocol RandomAccessCollection<Element>
```

but primary associated types didn't exist in older versions of Swift, so it still makes sense why the authors did this originally. Also, `RandomAccessCollection` redeclares more than just `Element`. There is also `Index`, `SubSequence`, etc.

By redeclaring the associated types, it is obvious at a glance when reading the documentation, what types a protocol requires.

Also, you can also write different documentation text on each associated type declaration.

```
protocol Foo<T> {
    /// something describing T...
    associatedtype T
}

protocol Bar<T>: Foo {
    /// something describing T that is more specific to Bar...
    associatedtype T
}
```

As for the `Element` in `Array<Element>`, that is a generic type parameter implementing the associated type requirement of `RandomAccessCollection` (and many other protocols). It is not an associated type declaration itself.

Comment: Thanks @Sweerper, I am still be wild about this "primary associated type" way . Can I understand the whole thing like this : when we create a Array object , this object will conform to the RandomAccessCollection protocol , and RandomAccessCollection need a  Element  association type, will get the specific element type for this association type from the array 's source code  (thanks to the compiler's Type Inference) . so we can omit the typealias in Array's source code

Comment: @ximmyxiao Primary associated type doesn't really have anything to do with this. My answer will still be the same if `Element` is not the primary associated type. Associated type requirements just requires the conforming type to have a type with a particular name. In this case, `RandomAccessCollection` requires its conformers to have a type called `Element`. `Array` indeed has such a type - it just so happens to be its generic type parameter.

Comment: @ximmyxiao Type aliases are often used to satisfy associated type constraints because they are an easy way to declare a type with a specific name, and make it be the same as an existing type. But there are other ways to declare types too, like declaring a generic type parameter, or declaring a nested struct/class/enum etc. All the associated type requirements needs is for `C.Element` to be a valid type, where `C` is the conforming type.

Comment: @ximmyxiao I would suggest posting a new question if you are still confused.

Comment: ,I know where I am wrong in understanding this,I used to think that the Element in Array and the Element in RandomAccessCollection are two different thing. but after writing a demo, I found that they are the same thing , If you create a Array with e Element (like:String), the RandomAccessCollection 's Element will also be String . because RandomAccessCollection is a protocol , It doesn't have storage(or something like this). So  when we set Element in Array it means we set the Element for RandomAccessCollection as well